# Custom icons in navigation bar Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have an issue with my custom button in Swift 3, I added into the Assets folder, in the ViewController and in the VC the icon is showed, but when I view in the simulator and in my phone the item shows only the form but not show the color and the icon itself.

Here is the image in the simulator and in my phone:

[image]

Here my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "back")
```

And for last here is the button icon:

[image]

Here in Photoshop
[image]

In xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you follow the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/) for creating Navigation Bar Items. Just guessing from your image it seems that you want the dark area to be colored and the white arrow to show as white or clear? In order to achieve this you need to make the white arrow transparent. Wherever your icon has pixel information will be colored in.

Comment: Yes, the image has 69 px, is transparent and in the VC is showed, but in the simulator dont..

Comment: Correct, but the arrow needs to be transparent as well. When I first answered I downloaded the png and was able to see this. You've also now added an image of photoshop which shows the arrow being filled in as white. You simply need to delete the white arrow so that you can see the through to the transparent background. In photoshop this would show the grid where the arrow is.

Comment: Your are  correct!! now is showing.. I don´t know it that inside of the image need to be transparent too., thank you. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the white arrow is actually a transparent area and not white?

You can then set the tintColor for the navigation controller. Try something like this: 
`navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(..the color you want..)`

Comment: Yes, the button is in png and have a transparent background